# Ubuntu 18.04 & PostgreSQL 10.9: What do I fill in the Properties Form to Get Them to Connect?

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, server, database-connection, pgadmin

I have PostgreSQL 10.9 and Ubuntu localhost installed on my machine.  I downloaded pgAdmin III on my machine for the first time.

I tried filling in the following based on a suggestion.

[image]

---

I get the following error:

[image]

Below is my config file:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try a basic connection filling these fields:

Name: a name of your connection (whatever in your mind)
Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: by default is 5432
Username: postgres
Password: password that you set during the initialization process

EDITED:

To solve the error in pg_hba.conf you need to add the following line in this file to allow users to connect via TCP using md5 encrypted passwords:

host all all 127.0.0.1 md5

This change requires a pg_reload_conf() signal. Use your terminal to access from psql command line: 
psql -U postgres

and execute the following sentence: SELECT pg_reload_conf();

If you can't access from psql, try to restart the service of PostgreSQL.

Try again from pgAdmin.

Comment: thank you; is the host always 127.0.0.1 by default?

Comment: When I tried out your suggestion, I got the following error which I've appended to my original question

Comment: I edited my answer with your error. Please take a look.